# Logging into Oracle XE, Apex works fine but connect with SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-xe

Ok so this may be because I'm not understanding Oracle XE very well.

Basically I've installed Oracle XE onto an Amazon EC2 micro instance following this guide;

http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2011/09/08/installing-oracle-11gxe-on-amazon-elastic-cloud/

Everything works fine, I logged into my-ec2-elastic-ip:9090/apex/apex_admin and created a "workspace" (whatever that is, I thought I was creating a database here?)

I can then go back to the my-ec2-elastic-ip:9090/apex url and log into the workspace.

Fine.

However now when I come to use SQL Developer to try and connect to the database I enter the following;

```
Connection Name: Test (just a label right? nothing to do with the workspace name?)
username: admin (username created for the workspace, correct?)
password: <password> (password for above user?)
hostname: <my-ec2-elastic-ip>
port: 1521
sid: xe (is this correct?)
```

It seems to connect fine but it repeatedly says the username/password is wrong. But its not, I've been very careful!

I've even created another user with a very simple name in the workspace and set their password to just "a" after disabling the password rules in apex/admin. Still I get the username/password wrong?

Whats going on? I assume I've set everything like ports etc up ok since I can get into apex and apex/admin just fine. But why does it complain about the username/password being wrong??

Have I not actually created a database yet?

Comment: Maybe you need to adjust the Security Group of the AWS instance to open the database port.

Answer (score 0):

You might well have created a database instance but when you create a workspace this does not necessarily equate to creating a database user.

Go into the main workspace page and navigate to "Administration" -> "Dashboards" and go to the "Database" tab screen.

What is the value of the dropdown "Schema" field?

This is the schema that Apex is looking at. If it's `SYS` or `SYSTEM` you need to create a database user via the SQL Workshop screens of log into your database instance as the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` user (as sysdba) and create a new database user to point your Apex workspace at.

(N.B. If you created a database instance it would have asked you for the `SYS` and `SYSTEM` passwords when you created it, if not, see [this thread](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=716808) for how to reset them).

Hope it helps...